# Input impedance of emitter follower

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, emitter-follower, small-signal

I decided to calculate the input impedance of the following emitter follower circuit as a practice.

[image: emitter follower diagram]

I used this well-known small signal model for the BJT:

[image: BJT model]

For voltage gain, I obtained

$$A_\text{v}=\frac{v_\text{out}}{v_\text{in}}=\frac{\beta/r_\pi-1/R_\text{B}}{\beta/r_\pi+1/R_\text{L}}$$

which is somewhat smaller that unity, as expected. For input impedance, I found

$$r_\text{in}=\frac{v_\text{in}}{i_\text{in}}=\frac{v_\text{in}}{v_\text{in}/R_\text{B}+(v_\text{in}-v_\text{out})/r_\pi}=R_\text{B}\;||\; (R_\text{L}||R_\text{B})\left(\beta+\frac{r_\pi}{R_\text{L}}\right)$$

I'd like to know if I've calculated it correctly. The book *The Art of Electronics* obtains \$r_\text{in}=R_\text{B}\;||\;(\beta+1)R_\text{L}\$ by a more or less different method.

Comment: For a small-signal model \$v_{in}\$ appears directly at the transistor's base, which then means that the resistor \$R_B\$ *has no influence* on your voltage gain \$A_v\$. So your first equation cannot be correct.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub, Thanks. I checked my calculations again and found no mistake. So I guess either the model I've used for BJT is not accurate enough or you're wrong that \$R_\text{B}\$ should not appear in the relation for small-signal voltage gain.

Comment: @apadana How do you calculate \$r_\pi\$? And yes, I get similar values for \$A_v\$. I'm just curious about your methods, just now. What are the steps you used to reach your \$A_v\$ expression?

Comment: @Mr.Snrub, \$r_\pi\$ is simply \$v_\text{be}/i_\text{b}\$.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub, To calculate \$A_\text{v}\$, for the node at collector, I wrote \$i_1=i_\text{c}+i_2\$, where \$i_1=v_{in}/R_B\$, \$i_c=\beta i_b\$ and \$i_2=-v_{out}/R_L\$. Also \$i_b = (v_{in}-v_{out})/r_\pi\$.

Comment: @apadana Rather circular as definitions go, as I see it. Isn't it then the fact that \$i_\text{b}=\frac{v_\text{be}}{r_\pi}\$? How do you establish the DC operating point? Or do you?

Comment: @apadana For example, I come up with:$$A_v= \frac1{1+\left[\frac{V_T}{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{BE}}}\right]\cdot\left[1+\frac{R_{_\text{B}}}{\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_{\text{E}}}\right]}$$which is based entirely upon the DC operating point. As it must be. Your argument appears "circular" to me.

Comment: @jonk, As you know, what I wrote above is the definition of \$r_\pi\$. It can be shown that it depends on the dc state of the circuit, i.e. \$r_\pi=V_\text{T}/I_\text{B}\$. Since dc analysis is usually done prior to ac analysis, at this stage \$r_\pi\$ is assumed to be given/known.

Comment: @apadana Okay. thanks. I'm just trying to see how you proceeded. (I also agree with the approximate result mentioned by the The Art of Electronics book. It just falls out, easily. I've no particular idea how you arrived at your result, yet.)

Comment: @jonk, Thanks for sharing your result. I'll compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hamm, the calculation are quite simple.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7CJHn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the small-signal model we have:

I apply KVL around the loop:

$$v_{in} = i_b r_\pi + i_eR_L $$

Additional we know that \$I_E =  I_B + I_C = I_B + \beta I_B = I_B(\beta + 1) \$

Therefore

$$v_{in} = i_b r_\pi + i_eR_L  = i_b r_\pi + i_b(\beta +1)R_L = i_b(r_\pi +(\beta +1)R_L) $$

And the input current is \$i_{in} = i_{RB} + i_b = \frac{v_{in}}{R_B} + \frac{v_{in}}{r_\pi + (\beta +1)R_L} \$

So now we can find the input impedance:

$$r_{in} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}} = R_B||(r_\pi +(\beta +1)R_L) $$

And if we treat the voltage across the RL resistor as output we will get:

$$v_o = i_e*R_L = i_b(\beta +1)R_L$$

Therefore the voltage gain is

$$ \frac{v_o}{v_{in}} = \frac{i_b(\beta +1)R_L}{i_b(r_\pi +(\beta +1)R_L)} = \frac{(\beta +1)R_L}{r_\pi +(\beta +1)R_L}$$

Also, notice that if we substitute for \$r_\pi = (\beta+1)r_e\$  the gain expresion becomes:

$$ \frac{v_o}{v_{in}} =  \frac{(\beta +1)R_L}{(\beta+1)r_e +(\beta +1)R_L} = \frac{(\beta +1)R_L}{(\beta+1)(r_e+R_L)} = \frac{R_L}{r_e + R_L} $$

A voltage divider equation.

Where \$r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E}\$

Comment: Thanks. By seeing your diagram, I noticed my mistake. I had used KCL for one of the grounded nodes, but had forgotten to take into account the current that returns to input signal source.

Answer (score 1):

@apadana, your equation for rin is correct, however, the gain expression is not.
Wihout any calculation we can see that RB cannot have any influence on Av (Vin ideal voltage source).

Correct: **Av=gmRL/(1+gmRL)**
with emitter transconductance **gm=(1+beta)/r_pi**

Introducing Av into the formula for rin gives the correct result .

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, \$i_\text{c}=\beta i_\text{b}=g_\text{m} v_\text{be}\$, so \$r_{\pi}=v_\text{be}/i_\text{b}=\beta/g_\text{m}\$. But according to you \$r_{\pi}=(\beta+1)/g_\text{m}\$. Why?

Comment: apadana, we are speaking about the role of the emitter current which is ie=(beta+1)ib and, hence the emitter-related transconductance gm,e. But we make no distinction between gm,e and gm,c because of the tolerances of BJT parameters . As you know, the difference between beta and (beta+1) is certainly much smaller than the tolerance of the beta value.